# modify grid-data for external filter in ng-grid angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I have to modify data of grid based on external generic filter for data grid.
I have searched and find out 2 ways to do so,

1. After changing grid data according to filter, use `$scope.gridApi.core.notifydatachange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL)`
2. add `$scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor( $scope.singleFilter, 200 );` in `$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi` and then inside `$scope.singleFilter` function change visibility of data according to filter.

Is it possible to filter data according to external filter and column filter together?

If YES, I want to know which method will go very well with column filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good idea to modify data for filter using `$scope.gridApi.core.notifydatachange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL)` function. As `$scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor()` is used by ng-grid internally for single column filter. And hence if we try to modify it, By default functionality of column filter will behave un-expectedly.